# PHP - Get text from a text field to put in widget

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

need some help! I have a client who needs a latest news section on their website. I have made a div to house the 'widget' although to edit the content (The text in the latest news box) my client would have to go into the widgets menu and edit raw html code, which I do not want him to be able to do.

I have thought up a solution, done a bit of research but have become a bit stuck as to what to do next.

I was thinking of using the plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/ to replace the text widget i currently have and using the following code;

```
    <?php
if (is_single() && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'NAME', true)) {
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'NAME', true);
}
?>
```

To grab a plain text textarea where my client can go, just to edit the text. Is this possible? I was thinking of having another button on the left of the admin panel called 'Latest News' where they can click and then it displays a textarea and a submit button.

Is this difficuly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you need more help, make a Fiddle so I can edit it

Comment: Why not just create a category for Latest news, create a new post, and display the latest post...That way, they can use the Wordpress editor, instead of the default text widget editor, which doesn't have any text formatting options bar.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, you must have a form with an input text or a textarea like:

```
<form method='post' action='action.php'>
  <textarea name='theText'></textarea>
</form>
```

And then in the `action.php` page you can get the content of this text area using `$_POST`:

```
$content = $_POST['theText'];
```

Finally you must insert this text into the widget using Javascript, inside the `action.php`:

```
<script>
  var text = '<?php echo $content; ?>';
  document.getElementById('WidgetSpaceId').innerHTML = text;
</script>
```

Feedback for more specific problems.

Comment: Thanks! - So if i needed to make another page on the wordpress admin panel which just contained a title, a subtitle, a textarea and a submit button (which just saves the text) how would I do it?

Comment: Just make a form as you like, each input have a name to get it's content in PHP with $_POST, and then pass the vars to javascript to insert it into the 'results page'. Otherwise, do you use a DB to store the news?

Comment: No, no database is used to store the news, it is just updated every week or so

Comment: Where would i put the action.php file?

Comment: in the server, same root as the page wich contains the form

Comment: Hi all, managed to do it using this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-widget/ thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what you want, but cant you simply add a posts widget and get posts from a given category? Then your client writes with the WYSISYG editor in Wordpress, posts in the news category?